# Subset dataframe by removing rows with same values in a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset my dataframe by removing rows which have same values in a specific column.

Here my dataframe:

```
        ID    Area        Date    Day 
1    21009  4390.0  1979-12-27   4835 
2    24005   178.5  1979-12-27   4835
3    27001   484.3  1979-12-27   4835   
4    27002   758.9  1979-12-27   4835  
5    38003   133.9  1979-12-27   4835
6    33014   272.0  2004-02-01  13637    
7    33029    98.8  2004-02-01  13637     
8    34003   164.7  2004-02-01  13637   
9    23118   220.8  2007-01-18  14502
```

My output should be:

```
     ID    Area        Date    Day 
1    21009  4390.0  1979-12-27   4835 
2    33014   272.0  2004-02-01  13637       
3    23118   220.8  2007-01-18  14502
```

I tried but didn't work:

```
df <- subset(df, Day == unique(Day))
```

and

```
df <- df[df == unique(df$Day), ]
```

Whereas the following code only return me a vector with `unique(df$Day)`, which is good, but I need all the dataframe subsetted:

```
df <- unique(df[ , 4] )
```

Comment: You want to use `?duplicated`

Comment: @docendodiscimus - which of course is referenced in the 'See Also' section of the `?unique` help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use duplicated:

```
df[!duplicated(df$Day), ]

#      ID   Area       Date   Day
# 1 21009 4390.0 1979-12-27  4835
# 6 33014  272.0 2004-02-01 13637
# 9 23118  220.8 2007-01-18 14502
```